# Getting Python error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Text'

Tags: python, win32com

I will try to write as many details as I can.

I'm the author of a tool called Virtual Forms. It is an ActiveX server control.

For now, I have only used it from VBA, VB.NET & C#
Now I want to use it from Python on windows.
It works, but, I got stuck on one line of code.

Here is the code:

```
import win32com.client as win32

vf1 = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('VirtualForm2.VirtualForm')

vf1.VFFile = r"C:\Users\WinPIS\Desktop\VFPython\VFFilePython.vf"

vf1.DatabaseType = 2

vf1.ConnectionString = r"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" \
                       "Port=3306;" \
                       "SERVER=myserver;" \
                       "DATABASE=mydatabase;" \
                       "USER=imtheuser;" \
                       "PASSWORD=hereismypass;" \
                       "OPTION=3;"

#vf1.OpenVirtualFormDesigner()

vf1.ShowVirtualForm("VF2")
vf1.TextBox("VF2", "[customerid]").Text = "888"
```

So I can call methods and pass some parameters to this control.

The control accepts the VFFile, DatabaseType and the ConnectionString parameter, because it opens the Virtual Form, connect to the MySQL database and displays the data. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

---

.
Then, in VBA I use this line of code to change the text that is in a textbox:

```
vf1.TextBox("VF2", "[customerid]").Text = "888"
```

And here is the screenshot that it works in VBA:

---

.
[image]

But when I try it from Python I got this error:

```
C:\Users\WinPIS\venv\VFPython\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/WinPIS/PycharmProjects/VFPython/VFPythonFile.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/WinPIS/PycharmProjects/VFPython/VFPythonFile.py", line 20, in <module>
    vf1.TextBox("VF2", "[customerid]").Text = "888"
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Text'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This only works in windows.

If you want to try it out you will need to install the setup for this Virtual Forms control that is in this download:

https://www.virtual-forms.com/sharing/Virtual%20Forms%20Framework2.0.0.31.zip

And here is the VFFile:

https://www.virtual-forms.com/sharing/VFFilePython.vf

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks,

Davor

---

---

UPDATE:

the 
    `print(dir(vf1))` 
gives this:

```
['CLSID', 'CloseAllVirtualForms', 'CommandButton', 'ConnectDatabase', 'DisconnectDatabase', 'EditRefresh', 'EditState', 'EditStateChange', 'GridRefresh', 'OpenVirtualFormDesigner', 'SectorVisible', 'ShowAboutBox', 'ShowVirtualForm', 'SplashShow', 'Splashhide', 'TextBox', 'TriggerBeforeFormOpen', 'TriggerCommandButtonAction', 'TriggerCommandButtonClick', 'TriggerCommandButtonGroupChange', 'TriggerCommandButtonViewClick', 'TriggerEditAfterSave', 'TriggerEditBeforeSave', 'TriggerEditChange', 'TriggerFlexChange', 'TriggerGenerateID', 'TriggerMenuFunction', 'TriggerTextBoxChange', 'TriggerTextBoxCheck', 'TriggerTextBoxGotFocus', 'TriggerTextBoxInit', 'TriggerTextBoxLostFocus', 'TriggerTextBoxValidate', 'VFInternalCheck', 'VirtualForm', '_ApplyTypes_', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_good_object_', '_get_good_single_object_', '_oleobj_', '_prop_map_get_', '_prop_map_put_', 'coclass_clsid']
```

and the
     `print(dir(vf1.TextBox("VF2", "[customerid]")))`
gives this:

```
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'count', 'index']
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback of your code, including line number?

Comment: I hope these are not your real credentials.

Comment: @Klaus D., I will change it, just want that you can test it.

Comment: Try printing `dir(vf1)` to see if there's a method for modifying text boxes.

Comment: I hope one day I will have as much trust in people as you have. ;)

Comment: @Joel I have updated the code, this 20 lines of code is all code. The error is trigered in the last line (20)

Comment: `TriggerTextBoxChange` seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all,

your directions moved me closer to the answer.

And the answer is, that I needed to include the [0] at the end.

So the error was in this line:

```
vf1.TextBox("VF2", "[customerid]").Text = "888"
```

And the answer is to add [0] to the end. Here is the code line that works:

```
vf1.TextBox("VF2", "[customerid]")[0].Text = "888"
```

Once again, thank you all